# TLS Certificates between mutiple clouds with random ips

Tags: azure, go, ssl, nginx

As a tls novice I'm really not sure what I should do here.

I have a client application in go using ListenAndServeTLS, that sends a request to a server application in go that is also using ListenAndServeTLS. I can send a request from the client to the server and validate a locally generated certificate.

When I update my client to talk to a proxy agent(c#) I have in Azure the opens a sslstream to the azure relay service that is connected to my server on my local machine. I get the following error. `Get https://<ip_address>:8080/hello: x509: cannot validate certificate for <ip_address> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs`

The IP address I am using is Dynamic and doesn't have a host or DNS. How do I validate my cert with the server if the IP changes with every request I make.

```golang
// Server Code
func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Write "Hello, world!" to the response body
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello, world!\n")
}

func main() {
    // Create a CA certificate pool and add cert.pem to it
    caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("../certs/cert.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)
    // Create the TLS Config with the CA pool and enable Client certificate validation
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        ClientCAs:  caCertPool,
        ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
    }
    tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:      ":8080",
        TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
    }
    // Set up a /hello resource handler
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", helloHandler)

    // Listen to port 8080 and wait
    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServeTLS("../certs/cert.pem", "../certs/key.pem"))
}
```

```golang
// Client Code
func main() {
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("../certs/cert.pem", "../certs/key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Create a CA certificate pool and add cert.pem to it
    caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("../certs/cert.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                // InsecureSkipVerify: true,
                RootCAs:      caCertPool,
                Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
            },
        },
    }

    // Request /hello over port 8080 via the GET method
    // r, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8080/hello")
    // Request /hello over HTTPS port 8443 via the GET method
    r, err := client.Get("https://<ip_address>:8080/hello")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Read the response body
    defer r.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Print the response body to stdout
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", body)
}
```

Comment: Use a load balancer and a domain name. Get the TLS cert for the domain name. It will work no matter what the back-end IPs are.

Comment: "My nginx server is rejecting the cert" no, it's not. Validation happens on the client, not the server (unless you're doing mutual authentication, but that doesn't seem to be the case here). The validation steps can be configured in [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config). Your description is very vague, but I would guess that it's enough to set the ServerName field. If you want a precise answer you have to add the TLS certificate and [the exact HTTP request](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequestOut) to the question.

Comment: Ok so from what I understand when I attempt to make the handshake from my client to the server, it's through a dynamic IP address. 
I get the following error: ```Get <ip_address): x509: cannot validate certificate for <ip_address> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs```
The connection I'm making doesn't have a static hostname or IP address, since they are dynaimcally generated by an azure service. Should I attempt to limit the IP range and wild card the SAN. Is there a different approach.

Comment: @Peter Updated the question hopefully its a bit clearer

Comment: Don't use IP addresses in HTTPS links.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, the requests are destined to a chosen proxy. Specifying the IP address in the URL is far simpler than creating dedicated http.Transports with custom Dial functions.

Comment: @Peter except that, specifically for "young players" like you say yourself, you will have to explain how to create a certificate with an IP instead of a name, and you will have to explain how to find a CA (they exist, but are rare) that will issue such certificate and what the validation entails. All of many details that can simplified by just saying: use names in HTTPS links and then you can have simple DV certificates.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, that is beside the point. The OP doesn't know the IP addresses in advance, so IP SANs aren't an option *anyway*. The question is how to validate the certificate if one can't use the DNS name because the request goes via a proxy, and that's done by specifying the server name explicitly. It's precisely why the option exists. [Here is the same option in nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_name), for instance.

Comment: @Peter It is precisely the point, see the code given: `r, err := client.Get("https://<ip_address>:8080/hello")` which triggered my comment "Don't use IP addresses in HTTPS links".

Answer (score 0):

First, to clear up a misconception: server's don't validate certificates. Certificates are cryptographic proof of an identitity, that is used by *clients* so they can be sure that they connected to the server they intended to. I.e. they want to be sure that the network connection hasn't been accidentially or maliciously directed to a different server. Thus, if certificate validation fails it's almost always because the *client* isn't happy, not the server.

When you make an HTTP request to `https://192.0.2.1:8080/hello` the client by default expects to be presented with a certificate that includes 192.0.2.1 in the subject alternative names (SAN) because that's going to be the value of the request's Host field (and as said above, the client want's to make sure that it did in fact connect to this server).

If you don't know the IP addresses in advance you cannot issue such a certificate and your only option is to change the client's expectation. That is what the [ServerName field in tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config.ServerName) is for. Simply set it to the certificate's common name (which should be a domain).

Comment: "server's don't validate certificates" They can. Each party of a TLS communication can have a certificate, which can be requested and verified by the other party. In HTTPS world it is mostly server certificates checked by clients, but even there some setups involve client certificates requested and checked by servers.

Comment: "Simply set it to the certificate's common name (which should be a domain)." It is long obsolete to use CN to store this, the SAN is the expected way to do it. Browsers either ignore or unfavor the CN part of a certificate.

Comment: When explaining TLS to young players, including irrelevant mutual authentication isn't helpful, in my experience. It just confuses more than it clears things up. It's quite clear in the question that the validation on the server works fine, so I deliberately glossed over it.

Comment: In my experience giving false information isn't helpful either.